# Swift @inlinable with multiple targets in a single SPM package

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, swift-compiler

I'm working on a series of SPM packages that work together, each of which has multiple targets within. I'm trying to figure out how much of my code to mark with `@inlinable` in order to allow the compiler to do cross-module optimizations.

Doing everything `public` and used across packages makes sense, do I also need to do the same thing for things used across targets within the same package? (I think the answer is yes for the same reason I need to mark those as `public` at least until the upcoming `package` access modifier is available).